# Reading MDF4-Files containing Ethernet Signals

Tags: ethernet, can-bus, mdf, asammdf

I am trying to read logger measurement files whicha are in the .mf4-format.
For this I am using asammdf as following:

```
self.mdf = MDF("file.MF4", version="4.10")
```

If the .mf4 file only contains CAN-Bus or Flexray signals, it works just fine.

Now I am trying to read .mf4-files that also contains Ethernet signals. The following error occurs:

> asammdf - ERROR - Expected "##CA" block @0x54f68 but found "b'##CN'" NoneType: None asammdf.blocks.utils.MdfException: Expected "##CA" block @0x54f68 but found "b'##CN'"

Is it possible to read MDF4 files containing Ethernet signals?

Comment: What asammdf version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 7.0.7

Comment: I've updated it now to version 7.3.2 and it seems to work. Thank you for the tip!